# Success page as a step in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout

Hello i'm looking to add the success page as a step in the step navigator. I followed the [following tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) on how to make an extra step but i'm unsure on how to connect the success page to it.

My current files:

success-step.html

```
<li id="success_step" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Success'" data-role="title"></div>

    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

    </div>
</li>
```

success-step.js

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'BigBridge_Checkout/success-step'
            },

            isVisible: ko.observable(true),

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();

                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                    'success_step',
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    //step title value
                    'Success',
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                     * sort order value
                     * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                     * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                     * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                     */
                    30
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
             * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
             * for switching to your custom step
             */
            navigate: function () {
            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">

                                    </item>
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">

                                    </item>

                                    <item name="success-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">BigBridge_Checkout/js/view/success-step</item>
                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                        </item>
                                    </item>

                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Any idea?

It also seems like the success step is instantly enabled at the moment on step 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just faking success as a step. I removed the above code and did the following:

I copied `progress-bar.html` to my module and added an `li` for the success step.

```
<ul class="opc-progress-bar">
<!-- ko foreach: { data: steps().sort(sortItems), as: 'item' } -->
<li class="opc-progress-bar-item" data-bind="css: item.isVisible() ? '_active' : ($parent.isProcessed(item) ? '_complete' : '')">
    <span data-bind="i18n: item.title, click: $parent.navigateTo"></span>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
<li class="opc-progress-bar-item">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Success'"></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

And in the `checkout_onepage_success.xml` I added a block to show a fake stepNavigator.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.progress.bar" template="BB_Checkout::progress-bar.phtml" 
cacheable="false"/>
```